# Is it safe to buy 3rd party plug adapters for the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charger

Apple doesn't sell just the removable plug end of the charger. I know buying 3rd party chargers are unsafe. However, is just the modular plug end safe?

[Here](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B072MZRVKD/ref=psdc_1375310031_t2_B00X7XFJSK) is an example of what I am talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is Safe.

That adapter does noting to Mac, it just redirects the socket power in different way.

[image]

No changes are made to the Power.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes perfect logical sense that it just redirects power. However, is there a trustable source which says the same? Just to be super extra sure.

Comment: I am EE with many Years of experaince, and as such I can tell you that is a passive device, and it wont harm in any way your Apple product. I can not speak about the manufacturing quality of that product.